# Ugly character in NSMenuItem's key equivalent

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsmenuitem, text-rendering

In my app's main menu I have a menu item that I'd like to set to the shortcut alt+"minus sign". I was able to set the key equivalent in IB, and it triggers as expected, but it's really ugly when running the app:

[image]

Even though in Interface Builder it's fine:

[image]

Do you have any idea why it's like that? Thanks!

Comment: Fascinating. My first thought was there is something wrong with Interface Builder's key input, but even if I set the key equivalent manually in code, it gets displayed this way. And the `Alt` is not even needed.

Comment: You were able to reproduce this? I'm using the German keyboard layout. I thought maybe that's messing up something.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce this (even without the `Alt` modifier). OS X is running in English, keyboard layout is U.S. (International).

Comment: I'm starting to think, this is "normal". I have the same character in Apple's Mail app in the Format > Style menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an OS X problem, here's a screenshot from Pixelmator:

[image: Pixelmator screenshot]

And even Preview.app has the same problem/bug (`View` menu):

[image: Preview screenshot - View menu]

Comment: Yes, it seems to be in all apps. Even Apple's. Never realized this until now.

Comment: Those menus seem to use a different font, don't you think? The shortcuts look like they're bold.

Comment: They're all using the standard font.

Comment: But compare the + sign in my app (the first screenshot is not in IB, it's the live app) to the + sign in Orangenhain's post.